# How to re-animate a div in CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/4jM2K/). Why am I not able to re-animate the animation after one click? The CSS rules and jQuery works only for first-time click.

```
<div class="animatetop"></div>
<button id="clicker">Click Me</button>

.animatetop {
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#FFCC33
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
        transform: translateY(50px);
        animation-delay:2s;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        animation-delay:2s;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
        transform: translateY(50px);
        animation-delay:2s;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
.fadeInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-delay:2s;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clicker").on("click", function () {
        // alert( "man nemidanam" );
        $('.animatetop').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add a class to an object once. Once it is there, adding it again does nothing. You'll have to remove the classes `animated fadeInUp` once the animation completes.

One way to do this is with `setTimeout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clicker").on("click", function () {
        // alert( "man nemidanam" );
        $('.animatetop').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        setTimeout(function(){

            $('.animatetop').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');

        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jM2K/3/)

Comment: Thansks David, can you please also let me know how toz add some delay to function through jquery?

Comment: If you want jQuery to wait a certain amount of time before executing, you can use `.delay(time in milliseconds)` as in @Felix's answer. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jM2K/7/ This will make the square transparent, wait 1 second, and then fade it back in over a period of 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [deque()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) to add and remove your classes in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clicker").on("click", function () {
        // alert( "man nemidanam" );
        $('.animatetop').addClass('animated fadeInUp').delay(500).queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("animated fadeInUp");
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    })
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jM2K/4/)**